# Powershell Get variable options

Tags: powershell

When working with powershell cmdlets, I often find that I need to set a switch to a finite number of options, but I don't know what options those are. I end up spending hours trying to google the option that I want. Is there a better way? I've tried looking at microsoft sites and Get-Help -examples, but none of those provide values for the switches that I want.

Here's an example.

```
Set-SPWebApplication <a couple of switches...> -AuthenticationMethod <String>
```

What are the acceptable values for -AuthenticationMethod?

This is just one example, but I run into this problem a lot. Im thinking there should be something in the Get-Help that would illuminate me, but that is often unhelpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I know is to pass an invalid option and you get a list in the error message:

> `PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy foo`
>
> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot bind parameter 'ExecutionPolicy'. Cannot convert value "foo" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy" due to invalid enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. **The possible enumeration values are "Unrestricted, RemoteSigned, AllSigned, Restricted, Default, Bypass, Undefined".**
>
> At line:1 char:20
>   + Set-ExecutionPolicy <<<<  foo
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

At this point you also have the type, so you can also use tab completion to get the valid values:

> `PS> [Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy]::`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I was hoping microsoft would have provided an easy way to look it up, like with get-help, but this works.

Comment: Get-Help is authored by someone, so in many cases the options are listed there and explained. But sometimes they are not, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test with `Set-SPWebApplication` but:

```
get-help  out-file -Parameter "encoding"
```

give an explanation of paramenter and a list of possible value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in conjunction with what [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052965/763026) has suggested

```
(get-help out-file).syntax ## gives you the sytax
```

Using [Christian's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052965/763026) after that

```
get-help  out-file -Parameter "encoding"
```

So, with the 1st one you can look at syntax and then use the second query to go into details of the syntax. You can replace `out-file` with `Set-SPWebApplication`.

Hope this helps.